# Failing to create 'mongoMappingContext' Bean when unit-testing with Fongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, unit-testing, junit, fongo

I am currently setting up the unit test for the project I am working on and I have run into a bit of a wall. The project I am working on is using mongoDB as its database so for unit-testing I wanted to use Fongo to simulation the database so I can test just the functionality itself. But whenever I run the tests it fails to properly create the mongoMappingContext Bean and the tests themselves fail. The underlying cause is a mappingException but I am not what is causing that. Has anyone else experienced a similar thing when unit-testing with Fongo? Thanks in an advance for all your help!

The test DB config file, TestDatabaseConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableMongoAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.x.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.x.service", "com.x.utility"})
public class TestDatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestDatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test_app";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        // uses fongo for in-memory tests
        return new Fongo("mongo-test").getMongo();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.x.service";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "test_app");
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
        OAuth2AuthenticationReadConverter converter = new OAuth2AuthenticationReadConverter();
        converterList.add(converter);
        return new CustomConversions(converterList);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
        mappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(getInitialEntitySet());
        mappingContext.setSimpleTypeHolder(customConversions().getSimpleTypeHolder());
        mappingContext.setFieldNamingStrategy(fieldNamingStrategy());

        return mappingContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactoryBean dbFactoryBean() throws Exception {

        MongoDbFactoryBean dbFactoryBean = new MongoDbFactoryBean();
        dbFactoryBean.setMongo(mongo());

        dbFactoryBean.setName("test_app");

        logger.info("Application database: {}", "test_app");

        return dbFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

The test file, MarketingAutomationServiceTest.java:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDatabaseConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MarketingAutomationServiceTest extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private MarketingAutomationService marketingAutomationService;

    @Test
    @UsingDataSet(locations = {"/one-marketing-automation-query.json"}, loadStrategy = LoadStrategyEnum.CLEAN_INSERT)
    public void testGetQuery(){
        MarketingAutomationQuery result = marketingAutomationService.getQuery("555a3662e4b024fe6d7a9d3f");

        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

The error trace I am getting from Spring whenever I run the test:

```
09:51:19.715 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@702657cc] to prepare test instance [null(com.x.service.MarketingAutomationServiceTest)]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in com.x.config.TestDatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both private final java.lang.reflect.Type org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.type and private final java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.type map to the same field name type! Disambiguate using @DocumentField annotation!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) ~[spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both private final java.lang.reflect.Type org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.type and private final java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.type map to the same field name type! Disambiguate using @DocumentField annotation!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.assertUniqueness(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:264) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:251) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:245) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:294) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.verifyFieldUniqueness(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:150) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.verify(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:142) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:442) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:296) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:442) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:296) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:442) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:296) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:442) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:296) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:442) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:296) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:442) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:296) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:257) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:363) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongoMappingContext() method is already part of the abstract class you are extending i.e. AbstractMongoConfiguration. I have similar setup and most the property seems correct other that 2 extra bean you have in you configuration file. CustomConversions and MongoMappingContext.

Can you try removing both the Beans you are creating again in you test configuration file TestDatabaseConfiguration.java

```
@Bean
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext()

@Bean
public CustomConversions customConversions()
```